# Do I need a Semantic Zoom control for each section of the "Zoomed Out"/overview page, or just one?

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I understand that the Semantic Zoom control is basically implemented in XAML this way:

```
<SemanticZoom>

    <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
        <!-- Put the GridView for the zoomed out view here. -->   
    </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>

    <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
        <!-- Put the GridView for the zoomed in view here. -->       
    </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>

</SemanticZoom>
```

What I'm confused about is, assuming I have a "start" or "main" page with six Gridviews on it, each of which will display individually when "zoomed in" to see their details, do I need a single Semantic Zoom to handle the entire collection of GridViews, or do I need a Semantic Zoom control for each GridView?

And if I only need one Semantic Zoom control to handle all of these (the Zoomed Out View will, indeed, be the same for all of them, by definition), how do I make the Zoomed In/detail view specific to the GridView selected?

IOW, if I have six GridViews with information for:

```
Green Bay Packers
Milwaukee Bucks
Baltimore Orioles
Rory Gallagher
Mark Twain
Abraham Lincoln
```

...how do I see to it that when the Zoomed In/detail view is activated, and the user "pinched out" on the "Mark Twain" grid, that the Mark Twain-specific page is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need one Semantic Zoom control.  But instead of having six different gridviews, can't you just have one bound to a grouped collection?  And then your GridView can use an ItemTemplateSelector to display your different data types.

See here for itemtemplateselector: http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/05/22/Using-Dynamic-XAML-in-Windows-8-Metro.aspx

I can provide some code if needed.

And regarding making sure the correct GridView is selected, the semantic zoom control handles that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Semantic zoom works best with a GridView bound to a grouped collection source.  The zoomed in and zoomed out views only support a GridView or ListView as their child element, so if you have 6 groups, you can achieve that with a single grid view.

In terms of the zoomed out view, the same type of control can be used to represent the groups.  This view can be customised to show the information that you need - e.g. The number of books in a section or maybe an overview of the section.

Handling the transition from the zoomed out view to zoomed in is easy enough, if a little convoluted in terms of setting up the binding (IIRC you need to specify the zoomed out binding in code) but moving in the other direction is not guaranteed to behave as you want it to.  If the zoomed out view is only one screen wide, for example, then it doesn't make sense to try to scroll to the previously selected group.

I am not in front of my dev machine right now so I'm afraid I can't put a sample together for you, but there are lots of examples online.

Comment: Assuming controls such as Grids and StackPanels can respond to gestures such as the "pinch out" and "pinch in" gestures, I may be better off doing that, sort of "faking" the Semantic Zoom experience, for my particular needs (my xaml editor is currently broken - VS won't display the GUI of *any* xaml file at present; waiting for Friday and the "real" Windows 8, etc.